# Mongoid is only inserting fields where the value differs from default

Tags: ruby, mongoid, mongodb

I have an admin page in a project, and I decided to change the names of a large section of fields.  So I changed the model to reflect the changes, and tried to set the new fields equal to the old fields by command line.  I couldn't figure out how to do it, so I basically added the new fields in my admin page, and set the values manually (hackish I know).

So let's say 2 of the new fields are:

```
field :foo, default: 0
field :bar, default: 9
```

Everything seemed to work fine and when I set foo and bar in admin, their values were saved.  But I noticed that I wasn't able to query against those values, as if they hadn't really been saved in my db.  So I looked in MongoHub, and indeed they weren't present there.  So I did a little googling,  and saw I needed to save my update.

So the code of the update now looks like:

```
if @stat_definition.update_attributes(params[:stat_definition])
    @stat_definition.save
    [other stuff]
```

And now any field that is set to something other than its default is getting saved, but any field that is left at its default is not.  What do I do to save those default values?

And what would have been the way to set foo to the field old_foo and bar to the value of old_bar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to run some queries like this, to set the default values:

```
t.update( { x : { $exists : false } }, { $set : { x : 77 } }, false, true
```

Comment: That does not really solve the problem as it will crop up again with new records afterwards.